# How can I get the behavior of a plain `auto` return type when using "expression SFINAE"?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, overload-resolution

Consider the following code.

```cpp
struct Widget {
    int& get();
};

template<typename X>
auto func_1(X& x) {
  return x.get();
}

template<typename X>
auto func_2(X& x) -> decltype(x.get()) {
  return x.get();
}
```

When called with an l-value of type `Widget`, the function `func_1` will be instantiated with return type `int` where function `func_2` will have return type `int&`.

Also, there is a difference between `func_1` and `func_2` in that "expression SFINAE" is performed for `func_2`. So, for types `X` which don't have a `.get()` member, `func_2` will not participate in overload resolution.

My question is: how can we get the return type behavior of `func_1` while still performing expression SFINAE?

The following `func_3` seems to work in the cases I tested, but I feel there should be a simpler alternative. Also, I'm not sure if `func_3` has exactly the same return type as `func_1` in all cases.

```cpp
template<typename X>
auto func_3(X& x) -> std::remove_cvref_t<std::decay_t<decltype(x.get())>> {
  return x.get();
}
```

Comment: *"how can we get the return type behavior of func_1 while still performing expression SFINAE?..."* Like you did in `func_3`.

Comment: *"I feel there should be a simpler alternative...."* This seems simple enough to me. Probably opinion-based.

Comment: You can use `func_1` in `func_2`  like `template<typename X>
auto func_2(X& x) -> decltype(func_1(x))` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KoK4YM4sv)

Comment: @user12002570: but as `func_1` is not SFINAE friendly, `func_2` is not neither.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `std::decay_t<decltype(x.get())>` is enough. Or `std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(x.get())>` (the latter doesn't perform array/function to pointer decay).

Or, in C++23 you can use `decltype(auto(x.get()))`.

---

But if you're wrapping a function, usually the plain `decltype` is more correct (e.g. in your case, if `get()` returns a reference, `auto` forces a copy).

Answer (score 3):

> My question is: how can we get the return type behavior of `func_1`
> while still performing expression SFINAE?
>
> The following `func_3` seems to work in the cases I tested, but I feel
> there should be a simpler alternative.

With the C++23 [`auto(x)`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0849r8.html) language feature, you can

```
struct Widget {
    int& get();
};

template<typename X>
auto func_3(X& x) -> decltype(auto(x.get())) {
  return x.get();
}
```

Comment: It seems more and more you need a PHD to even decently understand C++

Answer (score 0):

Just move the SFINAE check to another place.

The `noexcept` specifier is a good place because it conserves `noexcept`-ness as an added benefit:

```cpp
template<typename X>
auto func_2(X& x) noexcept(noexcept(x.get())) -> auto {
  return x.get();
}
```

Or if you have C++20 you can use a constraint:

```cpp
template<typename X>
auto func_2(X& x) requires requires { x.get(); } {
  return x.get();
}
```

Or really any alternative method that doesn't use the return type:

```cpp
template<typename X, std::void_t<decltype(x.get())>* = nullptr>
auto func_2(X& x) {
  return x.get();
}
```